# WordPress related issues

Tags: php, wordpress

If i want to go my sites wp-admin, then showing this: what should i do?

> Warning: Declaration of CloudFw_Walker_PageDropdown::walk($elements,
>   $max_depth) should be compatible with Walker::walk($elements,
>   $max_depth, ...$args) in
>   /home1/ducon/bangladeshswimmingpool.com/wp-content/themes/envision/cloudfw/core/framework/source.options.php
>   on line 250
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home1/ducon/bangladeshswimmingpool.com/wp-content/themes/envision/cloudfw/core/framework/source.options.php:250)
>   in /home1/ducon/bangladeshswimmingpool.com/wp-includes/pluggable.php
>   on line 1265
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home1/ducon/bangladeshswimmingpool.com/wp-content/themes/envision/cloudfw/core/framework/source.options.php:250)
>   in /home1/ducon/bangladeshswimmingpool.com/wp-includes/pluggable.php
>   on line 1268

Comment: Upgrade the theme to version 3.1.0 should fix the issue.

Comment: Quick solution is make wp_debug = false in wp-config.php file. It wil remove your warnings

Comment: Please update the plugins & themes and wordpress version if available

Answer (score 0):

Find the below code in wp-content/themes/your-theme/cloudfw/core/framework/source.options.php

```
public function walk( $elements, $max_depth) {
        $args = array_slice(func_get_args(), 2);
        $output = array();
```

And just add  **...$args** in function walk like below code:

```
public function walk( $elements, $max_depth,  ...$args) {
        $args = array_slice(func_get_args(), 2);
        $output = array();
```

Enjoy & Happy Coding

Comment: It worked, Thanks Mr. Abid Hasan. Thanks for such a great help.